# Windows 10, Git Bash, Julia, `Base.run` and no ANSI Color?

Tags: windows-10, julia, git-bash

Under some conditions, ANSI colors output by Julia in have stopped working for me.  I have tried this on Julia 1.6.3 and 1.7.0.

Under normal circumstances, colors work (this is in git-bash):

```
$ julia -e 'println("\33[1;31mhello\33[0m")'
hello
```

(Where hello is now bold and red).  But if Julia runs a command with `Base.run` before the `println`, I get:

```
$ julia -e 'run(`true`); println("\33[1;31mhello\33[0m")'
←[1;31mhello←[0m
```

This seems to be a julia thing:

```
$ python -c "import os; os.system('true'); print('\33[1;31mhello\33[0m')"
hello
```

(Again, the hello is red).
This also affects `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\>julia -e "run(`\"c:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\true\"`); println(\"\33[1;31mhello\33[0m\")"
←[1;31mhello←[0m
```

But it seems to be only the case for commands that come from the git-bash environment:

```
C:\>julia -e "run(`cmd /c exit`); println(\"\33[1;31mhello\33[0m\")"
hello
```

(in red, again).

I asked about this on Julia Discourse a while back, but didn't get any answers.  Does anyone here have any insight into what might be happening?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed to replicate this behavior and look kind of bug to me. I would recommend discussing on Julia Discourse. If you do so please remember to cross-link.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @PrzemyslawSzufel!  The discussion on Julia discourse is [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/base-run-and-ansi-colours/69611)